# VLOOKUP where the column to look for is a drop down list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am doing a little format in which I call data from other cells, from other worksheet to fill it out. I am using `VLOOKUP` to do that.

So as an example I have:

```
Name: (Drop down list)
Sex
Organization
Items
```

When I select a Name from the drop-down list, the fields for Sex and Organization are filled out automatically, because they have a `VLOOKUP` formula. The values are taken from a database in another sheet.

However, Items does not fill out. I get "0" as the value it returns. The reason for that, is that the value of items in the database is a drop-down list.

Example:

```
NAME  LAST NAME    ORG   ITEMS    SEX
Jhon   Adams       UN     item 1  (This is a drop down list (Male/Female)
```

The formula I am using is:
    `VLOOKUP(B2,A2:Y40,2,FALSE)`

- B2 - is the Name field (as a drop down list)... all of this in my little format
- A2:40 - is the entire range of the database
  2 - the column the field I want to excel to look up (In this case LAST NAME).

If I do the same formula for SEX, (so instead of `VLOOKUP(....,2,FALSE)`, it would be `VLOOKUP(......,4,FALSE)` it returns a "0". I imagine that it is because that column is made up with drop-down lists to select Male or Female from a drop-down list.

How can I make it so that when I do VLOOKUP I get the sex displayed correctly? 
Or which formula can I use so that it does display.

I have another case with ITEMS, but instead of selecting just ONE (Male OR Female) you can select many items as you want from the drop-down list How can I do it so that it displays the data correctly, instead of displaying "0".

Answer (score 0):

If Vlookup returns a zero that means that the cell it returns is empty. Whether or not the cell has a data validation drop down is unimportant. What matters is the value of the cell. If it has text, text will be returned. If it has a number, a number will be returned. If it is empty, a zero will be returned.

In fact, any formula that returns a cell value will show a 0 if the cell is empty.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I solved the isue with Male or Female, and I alrady made it work. I think I found out why it returns zero with items though. The cell that is a drop down list from the database (the one I want the value from), it's configured with a Macro to have multiple selections. For example: You can select Pencil, Pen, Ereaser, etc (as many as you want).